# SQL query selecting from list returns inconsistent table size in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a Bigquery table which is being updated daily via a batch operation and am trying to query the table to give me the most recent entries grouped by a post id (entries get duplicated every day). Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
*
FROM `stats_all_clients`
WHERE
created_date IN (
  SELECT max(
    created_date
    ) FROM `stats_all_clients`
  GROUP BY post_id
)
```

This returns a table with 1552 rows. Which is larger than the list from my "IN" statement. For example, if I only run the second SELECT statement:

```
SELECT max(
  created_date
  ),
  post_id 
FROM `stats_all_clients`
GROUP BY post_id
```

This table has 1021 rows, which seems correct.

I believe the issue is that since some files arrive into this table from an upstream process in quick succession, there are duplicate "created_date" timestamps, which is causing duplicate matches. In this table the "created_date" is the only field that determines the order of rows in the table.

I am wondering if there is a different approach to this query. If the table was ordered I could choose MAX(id) rather than MAX(created_date) after grouping by "post_id". I am struggling to work out how to group by "post_id", then order by "created_date", then select the max by row number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `row_number()` to get the most recent entry per post_id.

```
select *
from (
    select *, 
      row_number() over (partition by post_id order by created_date desc) as rn
    from `stats_all_clients`
    )z
where rn = 1
```

See [numbering functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/numbering_functions#row_number).